# Equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality implies $\overrightarrow v$,$\overrightarrow w$ linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Show that one gets equality in the Schwarz inequality if and only if $\overrightarrow v$,$\overrightarrow w$ are linearly dependent.

(I am supposing they want me to prove it in an inner product space we call V)

The $\Leftarrow$ part of the proof was pretty straightforward but I don't know how to go about the $\Rightarrow$ part because linear dependence requires us to show $\overrightarrow v$=$\lambda \overrightarrow w$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ but the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality only involves norms\lengths of vectors and not relations between the vectors themselves. I would appreciate tips on starting points.

Comment: @MiloBrandt, yes my bad, edited.

Comment: How did you proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $\overrightarrow v\neq0$(if $\overrightarrow v=0$ the proof is trivial), and take any norm of $V$. Fix an arbitrary $\lambda$ in the scalar field ($\mathbb{R}$in this case) and note that $$0\leq \|\overrightarrow u-\lambda \overrightarrow v \|^2=\langle \overrightarrow u-\lambda \overrightarrow v ,\overrightarrow u-\lambda \overrightarrow v \rangle$$
Is the first step in deriving the C.S inequality. Thus equality holds iff $$\|\overrightarrow u-\lambda \overrightarrow v \|=0$$
From our properties of norms we know then that  $$\overrightarrow u-\lambda \overrightarrow v=0 $$ and we have shown linear dependence.

Comment: It'd be more symmetrical (and closer to the definition of linear dependence) to take $0\leq \|\alpha u - \beta v\|^2$ and proceed. Then you don't need to consider the case where one is zero - it'd be built in to the proof naturally.

Comment: This is the proof I'm familiar with, but I'm sure your proof would have been along similar lines and you can adjust your inequality to equality accordingly.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I'd have to look at that. In my proof I end up dividing by $\|v\|$ so that's why I have two cases.

Comment: @K.Power, Thanks for your answer. I don't understand how you use C.S going from first line of operations to second. $|<\overrightarrow u,\overrightarrow v>| \le ||\overrightarrow u|| . ||\overrightarrow v||$ is the equation I have, we need to turn that into an equality as a supposition right?

Comment: @Sadem my first line of operations is how I derive C.S in the first place. It's the starting point of my proof for C.S. What proof did you use to derive C.S?

Comment: My book starts off almost the same way as you to prove C.S. but how do you conclude "equality holds iff $||\overrightarrow u - \lambda \overrightarrow v||=0$"?

Comment: @Sadem Well $0\leq \|\overrightarrow u-\lambda \overrightarrow v \|^2$ Is the only place in your proof that you should have an inequality. Thus the only way that you can derive an equality for C.S instead of an inequality is if that $\leq$ becomes an $=$.

Comment: But the C.S. inequality is the one I stated in my first comment isn't it? Shouldn't that inequality be turned into an equality and then proceed from there? How is equating 0 to the chosen norm using C.S. at all?

Comment: Well you don't use the C.S directly. The question is asking under what conditions will the C.S inequality become an inequality. You can only answer that by seeing how you derived the C.S inequality in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

From the proof of C-S. With $0\ne x=(x_1,..,x_n)$ and $0\ne y=(y_1,..,y_n).$ $$\|x\|^2\cdot \|y\|^2-(x\cdot y)^2=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_i y_j-x_j y_i)^2.$$ Now $x_i y_j=x_j y_i$ whenever $1\leq i<j\leq n$ iff there exists $k\ne 0$ such that $x_i=k y_i$ for $i=1,..,n.$ Use induction on $n$ to prove this.

The case $x=0\lor y=0$ is trivial.