# Equality harder than inequality

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> If $a_i \in \mathbb R^+$. Prove that $\displaystyle \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \right) ^{3} \leq n^2 \displaystyle \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^{3} \right)$
>
> Also, show that the equality holds iff
> $a_1=a_2=...=a_n$

I have proved the inequality using RMS-AM as well as cauchy-schwarz inequality. But I am stuck in proving the equality condition. Please help.

Comment: I think you should post your proof so people can point out how to show the equality condition from it.  Alternatively just use Holder's inequality (and use its equality condition).

Comment: I asked about condition for equality.

Comment: I edited my comment to accommodate that.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I'd go for contraposition, induction and assuming that w.l.o.g. $a_{n+1}$ is the unique largest number, i.e. $a_i < a_{n+1}$ for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ (you can assume the largest number is unique due to the strict monotonicity of both sides)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\bar{a} = \frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k$. Since all $a_k > 0$, so does $\bar{a}$. For each $k$, we have

$$a_k^3 - 3\bar{a}^2a_k + 2\bar{a}^3 = (a_k+2\bar{a})(a_k - \bar{a})^2 \ge 0 $$

Summing over $k$, the sum of LHS becomes

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^3 - 3\bar{a}^2\sum_{k=1}^n a_k + 2n\bar{a}^3
= \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^3 - n\bar{a}^3$$

Multiply the sum on both sides by $n^2$, we obtain

$$n^2\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^3 - \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right)^3 =
n^2 \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k + 2\bar{a})(a_k - \bar{a})^2 \ge 0$$

In order for the inequality to become an equality, the necessary and sufficient condition is
$$(a_k + 2\bar{a})(a_k - \bar{a})^2 = 0,\forall k
\quad\iff\quad a_k - \bar{a} = 0, \forall k$$
The last condition is equivalent to $a_1 = a_2 = \cdots = a_n$.

Comment: Nice direct proof without higher level theorems.

Answer (score 0):

By [RMS-AM inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) we know that equality holds if and only iff $a_1=...=a_n$, then we can refer to that proof.

Comment: Can you prove this?

Comment: By all means, we don't know how exactly the OP used those inequalities.  So we can't say for sure that this can be deduced from OP's proof.  (And the OP is not the type to google for proofs of well-known fact either, unfortunately.)

Comment: @DivyaPrakashSinha You can refer to [C-S equality case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1735058/equality-in-the-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-implies-overrightarrow-v-overrigh)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the question as
$$
\displaystyle \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i  \leq  \displaystyle \left(\frac1{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^{3} \right)^{\frac13}
$$
Now this is true, since it is the power mean inequality.

For the power mean inequality (as for all inequalities comparing means), it is well known that equality holds if and only if $a_1=a_2=...=a_n$.

A [reference](https://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2011/09/23/the-power-mean-inequality-and-some-related-topics/) for the last statement.

Comment: Please prove this well known fact.

Comment: The proof is in the reference I gave.

Answer (score 0):

By Holder
$$n^2\sum_{i=1}^na_i^3=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n1\right)^2\sum_{i=1}^na_i^3\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt[3]{1^2a_i^3}\right)^3=\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^3.$$
The equality occurs for
$$(1,1,...,1)||(a_1^3,a_2^3,...,a_n^3)$$ or for
$$a_1=a_2=...=a_n$$